# Fix numbering on CSV files that have deleted lines

Tags: python, csv, glob

I have a bunch of CSV files that I have edited and gotten rid of all of the lines that have 'DIF' in them. The problem that I realized later is that the count number in the file stays the same as before. Here is an example of the CSV before I edit it.

```
Name    bunch of stuff                          
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
Count   11                           
NUMBER,ITEM
N1,Shoe
N2,Heel
N3,Tee
N4,Polo
N5,Sneaker
N6,DIF
N7,DIF
N8,DIF
N9,DIF
N10,Heel
N11,Tee
```

This is how the output CSV looks. I want the number next to 'Count' to equal the number now in the 'ITEMS' column as well as have everything in the 'NUMBER' column to be sequential.

```
Name    bunch of stuff                          
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
Count   11                           
NUMBER,ITEM
N1,Shoe
N2,Heel
N3,Tee
N4,Polo
N5,Sneaker
N10,Heel
N11,Tee
```

Here is my current code that does that. It does what I want it to, but it screws up the rest of the CSV like I mentioned above.

```
import csv
import glob
import os

fns = glob.glob('*.csv') #goes through every CSV file in directory

for fn in fns:
     reader=csv.reader(open(fn,"rb"))
     with open (os.path.join('out', fn), 'wb') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        for row in reader:
            if not ' DIF' in row: #remove DIF
                w.writerow(row)
```

I've tried a few small things to fix it, but I am fairly new to programming and nothing I try seems to do much. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: By "fix it", do you mean renumbering the lines so that they are consecutive? Does this need to be done in the files that you've already processed, or in new files? How about a simple counter that is inserted at the beginning of each row that is written.

Comment: It can be done to either the ones I have processed or the ones I have not. I have the originals. I want the numbering to be consecutive so instead of N5 then N10, I want it to be N5 N6 N7. What do you mean by a simple counter?

Comment: @HAMZASurti This is simply an observation.  Martijin has spent considerable time working on your problem.  He does that (I assume) because he wants to give back, help you but also improve his reputation.  One of the ways people earn reputation is by having their answers upvoted - this indicates that you learned something.  Another way is by clicking the check mark - indicating that you accept his answer as addressing your needs.  I upvoted his answer because I learned something from it. This is a great site and I think you will benefit. But please respect his effort by improving his rep.

Comment: @PyNEwbie: I do not have the reputation yet to upvote any answers however I have checked his answer. I really do appreciate his help and I do not mean to disrespect anyone.

Comment: @HamzaSurti I am sorry I did not think you meant to disrespect anyone I just wanted to make sure you understood how this system worked.  I have greatly benefited from the folks who spend time answering questions and so . . .   Cheers and welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to update the count, then you have to read twice and count the number of rows you are keeping *first*. You can keep a separate counter to rewrite the first column once you are writing the matched lines:

```
import re

numbered = re.compile(r'N\d+').match

for fn in fns:
     # open for counting
     reader = csv.reader(open(fn,"rb"))
     count = sum(1 for row in reader if row and not any(r.strip() == 'DIF' for r in row) and numbered(row[0]))

     # reopen for filtering
     reader = csv.reader(open(fn,"rb"))

     with open (os.path.join('out', fn), 'wb') as f:
        counter = 0
        w = csv.writer(f)
        for row in reader:
            if row and 'Count' in row[0].strip():
                row = ['Count', count]
            if row and not any(r.strip() == 'DIF' for r in row): #remove DIF
                if numbered(row[0]):
                    counter += 1
                    row[0] = 'N%d' % counter
            w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: But this does not give him a new value for Count - it leaves the existing which will be off by the number of items deleted

Comment: It is unclear what the numbering scheme *should* be. Starting at 1 is just as good a guess. :-)

Comment: Sorry I was not clear it is this line in his file that also needs to change  Count   11

Comment: I keep getting an IndexError saying the list index is out of range

Comment: @PyNEwbie: Indeed, I missed that.

Comment: @HamzaSurti: That means you appear to have rows that are empty then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I do have one empty row in each CSV. How can I fix the code to accommodate this?

Comment: @HamzaSurti: I already did so; `if row` tests if there is *any* data in that row.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It still get the same error no matter how I try to fix it

Comment: @HamzaSurti: ah, `row[0]` could be an empty string perhaps. Adjusted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It works but it no longer gets rid of the 'DIF' statements. Also, the header information that starts with N such as 'Name' or 'Number' get changed to N1. Can I change something to start after the header?

Comment: @HamzaSurti: Adjusted; I switched to a regular expression for simplicity, it tests that the first column starts with a `N` and is followed by 1 or more digits. I also adjusted the `DIF` test; your own code suggested you had a space in front of it, but looking at your data, it's the second column that should be tested really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The `DIF` statements still do not go away. My CSVs do indeed have a space in front of the `DIF`. I have edited your code to account for that and I have also edited part of one of the CSVs manually to see if your code would work for `DIF` with out a space in front. Neither worked.  Can you possibly think of anything else that could be wrong? Thank you so much for all of your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you print the rows as Python loads them? Just `print row` and tell me what that looks like for a row with `DIF` in it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ['N18', ' DIF', '<1.000','    ','      ','F55','    ',]

Comment: I keep getting an error saying the integer has no value strip, but it still wont work after I tried to make them into strings by putting `str` in the beginning.

Comment: @HamzaSurti: That sounds like there is something else wrong entirely. What is the traceback? Use a pastbin to communicate that, don't put that in a comment. The `row` lists from a CSV file are **always** strings.

Comment: if row and not any (strip() =='DIF' for r in row):
attributeerror: 'int' object has no atrribute 'strip'

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear I think you want N to be updated with the number relative to the position on the updated list  I am assuming you are on Windows

Since it appears that you are not using row dictionaries I am going to do it a little differently

```
my_files = glob.glob('c:\\thedirectory\\orsubdirectorywhereyourfilesare\\*.csv')
for each_file in my_files:
    initial = open(each_file).readlines()
    no_diff = [row for row in initial if 'DIF' not in row]
    newCount =  len(no_diff) - no_diff.index('NUMBER,ITEM\n') -1  #you might have to tweak this
    outList = []
    counter = 0
    for row in no_diff:
        if 'Count' in row:
            new_row = 'Count ' + str(newCount) + '\n' # this is a new line character
            outList.append(new_row)
        elif row.startswith('NUMBER'):
            outList.append(row)
        elif row.startswith('Name'):
            outList.append(row)
        elif row.startswith('N'):
            print counter
            row_end = row.split(',')[-1]
            row_begin = 'N' + str(counter + 1)
            new_row = row_begin + ',' + row_end
            outList.append(new_row)
            counter += 1
        else:
            outList.append(row)
    outref = open(each_file)
    outref.writelines(outList)
    outref.close()
```

I copied this into a file

```
'Name    bunch of stuff                          \n'
'header stuff    stuff                           \n'
'header stuff    stuff                           \n'
'header stuff    stuff                           \n'
'header stuff    stuff                           \n'
'header stuff    stuff                           \n'
'Count   11                           \n'
'NUMBER,ITEM\n'
'N1,Shoe\n'
'N2,Heel\n'
'N3,Tee\n'
'N4,Polo\n'
'N5,Sneaker\n'
'N6,DIF\n'
'N7,DIF\n'
'N8,DIF\n'
'N9,DIF\n'
'N10,Heel\n'
'N11,Tee'
```

I ran the code above (which I had to tweak) and got this result

```
'Name    bunch of stuff                          \n'
'header stuff    stuff                           \n'
'header stuff    stuff                           \n'
'header stuff    stuff                           \n'
'header stuff    stuff                           \n'
'header stuff    stuff                           \n'
'Count 7\n'
'NUMBER,ITEM\n'
'N1,Shoe\n'
'N2,Heel\n'
'N3,Tee\n'
'N4,Polo\n'
'N5,Sneaker\n'
'N6,Heel\n'
'N7,Tee'
```

Now the other approach here and on you second question are definitely more elegant but elegance only comes after you really understand the code.  There are too many moving parts in my opinion.  You need to

1. read a file
2. handle parts of the file
3. write it back out

If you add in regular expressions and csv handling then you are exploding all of the areas you can get into trouble.  Those are great tools and I use them often but now to start learning how to program in Python
Otherwise look at csv.DictReader if your header is not too messy

Comment: whenever I tried this code, I kept getting syntax errors that made no sense to me. I've tried to change what I could but I kept getting synatx errors

Comment: post them you really should add 20 to 30 lines of exact data

Comment: `else out_list.append(row):` is giving me a syntax error. What do you mean by exact data? My CSV?

Comment: Sorry I did not realize how badly it was formatted and I did inconsistently use variable names, I think it is fixed.

Comment: when I run it, i get a syntax error that says `unexpected character after line continuation character` and point to the parenthesis at the end of line 1. Also why did you add the `\n'` in the csv files? I am sorry to keep bothering you about this but I am in a jam. I really do appreciate the help quite a bit.