# Error while editing many CSV files

Tags: python, csv, counter, glob

I asked this question a few days ago because I needed help with editing some CSV files: [Fix numbering on CSV files that have deleted lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257999/fix-numbering-on-csv-files-that-have-deleted-lines/18258274?noredirect=1#comment26921500_18258274).
The people of Stack Overflow helped me out a great deal however I keep getting an error saying `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'.` The problem is that all the information in my CSV files are not integers. Being the python newbie that I am, a few days of trying to fix it only made things worse. Here is what I have from my previous question that gives me the error:

```
import csv
import glob
import os 
import re 

numbered = re.compile(r'N\d+').match

for fn in fns:
     # open for counting
     reader = csv.reader(open(fn,"rb"))
     count = sum(1 for row in reader if row and not any(r.strip() == 'DIF' for r in     row) and numbered(row[0]))

 # reopen for filtering
 reader = csv.reader(open(fn,"rb"))

 with open (os.path.join('out', fn), 'wb') as f:
    counter = 0
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row and 'Count' in row[0].strip():
            row = ['Count', count]
        if row and not any(r.strip() == 'DIF' for r in row): #remove DIF
            if numbered(row[0]):
                counter += 1
                row[0] = 'N%d' % counter
        w.writerow(row)
```

The code is essentially supposed to run through a bunch of CSV files and delete all the lines that have 'DIF' in them and fix the numbering due to deleted lines. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: did you even try my approach?  The problem I think is that you are doing more than you need to do if you read it in as a string then it has to be a string and then you don't have to worry about the nature of the data.  adding csv to the mix adds complexity that is probably not needed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix numbering on CSV files that have deleted lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257999/fix-numbering-on-csv-files-that-have-deleted-lines)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest might be to wrap r in str(). But at the same time, why don't you read the file in just once, makes it easier:

```
import csv
import glob
import os
import re

numbered = re.compile(r'N\d+').match

for fn in fns:
     reader = csv.reader(open(fn,"rb"))

     # filter out 'DIF' rows here
     rows = [ row for row in reader 
              if not any(str(r).strip() == 'DIF' 
                   for r in row) ]

     # count numbered rows
     count = len([row for row in rows if row and numbered(row[0])])

     with open (os.path.join('out', fn), 'wb') as f:
        counter = 0
        w = csv.writer(f)

        for row in rows:
            if row and 'Count' in row[0].strip():
                row = ['Count', count]

            if row and numbered(row[0]):
                counter += 1
                row[0] = 'N%d' % counter

            w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I got an error saying object of type 'generator' has no len. What does that mean?

Comment: sorry, fixed - cannot take len() of a generator expression

Comment: the code worked however there was no change in my CSVs. Would you have any ideas on how that could be?

Comment: your code does not change the csv's, it writes the changed files into `out/` folder

Comment: the files in the output folder did not change. In the sample I am testing this on, there are  six cells with `DIF`. Is there anything else it could possibly be?